# Cohomology of finite birational morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, birational-geometry

Let $f:Y \to X$ be a finite birational morphism between projective varieties (over $\mathbb{C}$) with $Y$ non-singular. I want to understand the cokernel of the pull-back morphism from $H^q(X,\mathbb{Q})$ to $H^q(Y, \mathbb{Q})$. In particular, I am interested in the cases when the cokernel vanishes. Any reference of such results will be very helpful.

Comment: @NickL $f$ is finite in my question. So every fiber is zero dimensional. Your example of blow-up does not fit the hypothesis. I suspect the cokernel always vanishes due to Corollary $1.9$ of Weber's article "Pure Homology of Algebraic varieties", but I am not sure.

Comment: You probably already know this: if your $f$ is not an isomorphism, then $X$ is non-normal (by Zariski's Main Theorem).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi But the Corollary does not use normality... Do you suspect some obstruction to the vanishing of cokernel coming from the normalization?

Comment: There is an exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_X\rightarrow f_*\mathbb{Q}_Y\rightarrow \mathscr{C}\rightarrow 0$, where $\mathscr{C}$ is a sheaf with support on the singular locus of $X$. Your question is whether $H^q(X,\mathscr{C})$ is zero or not; this depends very much on the situation -- it should be easy to find examples of both cases.

Comment: Probably the most generally useful criterion is that the cokernel vanishes when $q$ is greater than twice the dimension of the locus where $f$ is not an isomorphism, by what abx said and general bounds for the cohomological dimension of varieties.

Comment: To make an example where the cokernel does not vanish, let $Y$ be the blowup of $\mathbb P^2$ at two points and let $X$ be obtained by gluing the two exceptional divisors together. Then every cohomology class in $H^2$ that's a pullback from $X$ must have the same integrals on both exceptional divisors. The space $Y$ is projective because the line bundle $\mathcal O(3-E_1 - E_2)$ is ample and descends to $Y$.

Comment: I think there is a typo in Corollary 1.9 of that paper and it should say "is isomorphic to the image $\iota_Y^*$".